# How do I use Google Custom Search with Drupal without installing a module?

Tags: drupal, search, search-engine

I'd like a more capable search for my website. My current search is unable to ignore spelling mistakes and since our site is a multi lingual we really need this capability. Google has a great way of doing this.

I'm aware of the Google custom search, how do I install this to drupal without installing a module?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: _"how do I install this to drupal without installing a module?"_. You can't, there are hooks implemented that have to happen at the module level. You'll either need to write your own and install it, or (much easier) use the existing module

Comment: Hi Clive, how does one activate the CSE module in Drupal 6. I've installed but results aren't showing

Answer (score 0):

Here is the documentation for how to add GCS to your web site by pasting some code into your template (or a block or node)

https://developers.google.com/custom-search/docs/element.

I did this method on http://www.greens.org.nz/ so see that web site for a working example.

Comment: Hi Rimu, possible to give a step by step guide when you have a minute? Highly appreciated.

Comment: There is one in the link I provided, about 2 or 3 screens down.